# What other software is available to remove old files/kernels to increase space and cleanup drive?

Tags: kernel, uninstall, purge

Like many others users, I need to remove files/kernels to increase space because I'm getting the error message that says I can't update because I have don't have enough space in `/boot`. I've searched for months, and I've found many answers that are similar to each other, but most are not applicable to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, or the instructions are not beginner-friendly. Ubuntu-tweak is no longer supported by the dev, and I don't know if anyone else is picking that up. I found Synaptic Package Manager, so I'm studying that for now, but I'd like to know if there are any other programs that serve a similar purpose. Is there anything else out there? (I'd welcome updated info for command-line for 14.04 LTS as well.) Thanks for your input.

Comment: Why do you think Ubuntu tweak not supported ? It does the job.

Comment: Hi. I did find a link to download it, but the dev is no longer supporting it. (The site has to be translated. Previous ubuntu-tweak links now go there.) [Formally closed the Ubuntu Tweak Related Sites](http://imtx.me/archives/1947.html). I've never installed using the command line (a learning newbie), so once I figure that out, I will try it. I've read a lot of good things about it in forums.

Comment: Please check the details and release notes on this page. In the very last release the support for 14.04 was added. [Ubuntu Tweak Tool, launchpad-release notes](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/0.8.x/0.8.7) I am using 0.8.7 version on 14.04

Comment: Thanks for that link @ankit7540. That is the version I downloaded the other day, so yay, and I'll give it a go after I figure out the install process.

Comment: Installation worked, and now I'm trying to figure everything out. While researching here, I've found that a lot of people have lost configurations, desktops, menus, etc after using janitor in U-T. I'm not sure what they did, but I want to avoid that if possible, so I'm thoroughly reading those posts, and also trying to find out what some of my packages are before I mess with them. It may seem like a lot of unnecessary work to those who understand all of this, but I need to understand it and I'm really enjoying this process.

Comment: this learning is addictive ;)

Comment: Yes, it surely is. :)

Comment: May I ask why you chose to have `/boot` on a separate partition and how much space it holds? That doesn't seem like a sensible choice for a Linux beginner.

Comment: I didn't make that choice. There wouldn't be any reason for me to even attempt something like that- especially as a beginner. This was a new install on a new 480 GB SSD. The boot partition is set to 255 MB. From what I remember, I was asked if I wanted to partition the drive, and I said NO. There was no need as I wasn't going to dual boot or anything like that.  I don't know why it happened, but I'm upset about it, and I'm trying to figure out how to change it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend letting `apt` handle this for you, using the command:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

That should do everything you need. Once the process is complete, it's worthwhile checking the filesystem locations that Zanna has mentioned in her answer.

On a sidenote, I prefer to keep at least one old kernel version that I know works, just incase the current kernel suddenly stops working. I'm probably just being paranoid, but it's nice to have one to revert to.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Arronical! I'm nervous about removing anything, so having a "backup" kernel seems like a good idea to me.

Comment: I've found that `apt-get autoremove` leaves me with the current kernel and the most recent previous version. It lists what will be removed and asks you to confirm that you want to continue. For your usage it's probably best to see which version numbers are in `/boot` then check that the command won't remove any you want to keep. It does remove all of the files mentioned by Zanna, and update grub for you too. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I'm checking to see what versions are in /boot now. Trying anyway. I'm pulling it all together in my head (a risky venture), and I'll update all of you when I've succeeded. Thanks so much!

Comment: I have used this 2 (possibly 3) times now, and it has worked very well each time. I used it when I couldn't update, and after using it, I could update. Yay, and thank you again!

Comment: Good stuff, glad it's working well for you. It's always nice to have a reliable way to do common tasks, especially when it doesn't involve installing another package!

Comment: Definitely! I actually refer back to this page every time I need to do this. :) I'm so grateful for your help, and everyone else's here, too. :)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @Arronical that `autoremove` does everything you want. In the interest of getting to know your system better, you could do all the work that `autoremove` does yourself. Start by opening a terminal and typing

```
uname -r
```

Write it down & for whatever you love most, do not hurt anything with that release number, or you will nuke yourself. And in general,  type carefully and check what you entered before `sudo rm`ing anything ;)

I recommend always keeping at least 1 'spare' kernel that I know works well installed, in case of bugs (or just wanting to fiddle around)

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

to identify kernels currently installed, then purge:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x-x-generic
```

replacing `x` with the correct numbers for the release you want to remove

```
sudo update-grub
```

which seems to happen automatically when purging anyway. But no problem to run it again just in case. Next

```
ls /boot
```

and if anything remains relating to the kernel version(s) you removed just remove it

```
sudo rm /boot/name-of-file-to-remove
```

(replace with the actual name obviously). Next

```
ls /lib/modules
```

and if the kernel(s) you removed still has a directory in there

```
sudo rm -r /lib/modules/name.of.directory.to-remove
```

next

```
ls /usr/src
```

and if the kernel(s) you removed still has headers in there

```
sudo rm -r /usr/src/linux-headers-name.of.version.to.remove
```

finally (usually gets updated but just in case)

```
ls /var/lib/initramfstools
```

and once again remove anything with the version(s) you're deleting.

---

Mostly from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/153193/527764) but I have added *all the places* for completeness.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed response, Zanna. It's much appreciated. I'm going to try it this weekend. Thanks again!

Comment: You're more than welcome, enjoy tidying up!

Answer (score 1):

I am still using **ubuntu-tweak** on 14.04.

It works nicely, and its janitor only requires a single click and two times typing the sudo password; and old modules and kernel stuff is gone for good. I find that far better than the other "manual procedures" listed so far.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that. I've heard a lot of good things about ubuntu-tweak, but I was sad to hear the dev decided to terminate the project, and I don't know whether or not anyone picked it up. Many of the previous links only point to this site now. [Formally closed the Ubuntu Tweak Related Sites](http://imtx.me/archives/1947.html)

Comment: But I have to add: you are fully correct: the PPA page for ubuntu-tweak explicitly says: no longer maintained. And on 16.04, the 0.87 deb won't install (cleanly) any more.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate that. I wish I was wrong. Sadly, the links I posted to the devs info don't work anymore either. As I mentioned above, I've seen recent posts from people who say they've lost configurations, desktops, menus, etc after using janitor. They didn't mention what they did from A to Z, so I'm a little scared to try it now. I chickened out at the last second.  Since it won't install cleanly on 16.04, I guess no one has taken over the project.

Comment: Lets be precise: I used the janitor for packages/kernels ... and never had problems!

Comment: That's awesome, and I'm glad to hear it. I hope that will be my result as well.

Comment: @CodingMama Fyi: I am using the ucaresystem-core since lately on 16.04; and I am quite happy with it.

Comment: Great! Thanks for letting me know. It's definitely something else to consider.

Answer (score 0):

https://utappia.org/2016/03/28/ucaresystem-core-v3-0-released-and-available-in-ppa/

this one works quite well and thorough and safely.

Comment: I hadn't heard of that one. Thanks so much for the information. I really appreciate it!